# How to Make Drawer Layout Content Swipable

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, navigation-drawer, drawerlayout

I have a ViewPager inside Drawer Layout of Navigation Drawer.When I Open Drawer by Swiping Left if Opens but when I try to swipe through View of ViewPager the Drawer Close on Swiping from left to Right.
So I want the Navigation Drawer to be able close only if we start swiping from outside the Drawer Layout.
I have tried somethings but unable to find the answer to it.
Here is a Screen Shot of what I want:-->

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2IuJRFj9vQCS2szRlVWWTlfWVE/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1):

I think you should try to implement a simple Navigation Drawer (left to right), then you change the orientation of swipe. Here is a simple navigation drawer code:

Modify your layout to be a drawer layout:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">
<!-- The main content view -->
<FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
<!-- The navigation drawer -->
<ListView
        android:id="@+id/drawer"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"/>
```

Implement a ListView, it will be the items of your navigation drawer

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/textView"/>
```

Then you should implement the java code of your activity connecting the ListView with your NavigationDrawer listeners and Activity code.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private String[] mPlanetTitles;
private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
private ListView mDrawerList;
private CharSequence mTitle;
private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mTitle = "test";

    mPlanetTitles = new String[]{"one", "two", "three"};
    mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.drawer);

    // Set the adapter for the list view
    mDrawerList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            R.layout.drawer_list_item, mPlanetTitles));
    // Set the list's click listener
    mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new DrawerItemClickListener());

    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

}

@Override
protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
    mDrawerToggle.syncState();
}

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Pass the event to ActionBarDrawerToggle, if it returns
    // true, then it has handled the app icon touch event
    if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
        return true;
    }
    // Handle your other action bar items...

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

/**
 * Swaps fragments in the main content view
 */
private void selectItem(int position) {
    Toast.makeText(this, R.string.app_name, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    // Highlight the selected item, update the title, and close the drawer
    mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
    setTitle(mPlanetTitles[position]);
    mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
}

@Override
public void setTitle(CharSequence title) {
    mTitle = title;
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
}

private class DrawerItemClickListener implements ListView.OnItemClickListener {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        selectItem(position);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Thanks fopr this.. but It's not a solution i think ... i will try extending the Navigation Drawer Class and Override the data on Touch Event to get the Desired touch Area... thanks.